# Looking for a clean way to install daemontools-encore on OS X

Tags: gcc, osx-snow-leopard

**CONTEXT:**

I want to use an OS 10.6.8 system to test [some patches to daemontools encore](https://github.com/wolfen/daemontools-encore).

For the gcc toolchain I need either XCode or [this gcc installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/). I chose the latter, which appears to work nicely on my system.
And [daemontools-encore is available on githib](https://github.com/bruceg/daemontools-encore), from which I fetched it using a git client downloaded from [github.com](http://www.github.com).

**PROBLEM:**

Running ./makemake from the distribution directory gives me an empty Makefile, and the following messages (seemingly regardless of whatever tweaks I make to the *conf files):

```
Calculating targets...
Building Makefile...
./makemake: line 114: makemake.TARGETS: Is a directory
sort: read failed: makemake.TARGETS: Is a directory
rm: makemake.TARGETS: is a directory
done.
rm: makemake.TARGETS: is a directory
```

I had expected a largish (~300 line) Makefile to be produced (as per the original distribution of daemontools 0.76), making subsequent "make install", etc. operations possible.

**EDIT:**

I'm working with [this version of daemontools-encore](https://github.com/bruceg/daemontools-encore/commit/c6373f2982393e666cc02c9b70efb0f279b5de06).

Comment: Bruce Guenter himself diagnosed the issue, and writes (via github): "The problem is that the filesystem on OSX appears to be case insensitive, so it creates a directory "makemake.targets" and tries to write to "makemake.TARGETS" (which gets renamed to just TARGETS). Obviously this doesn't work. Change line 4 of makemake to some other distinct filename to get it working. I'll fix the source on my end."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggstion by Bruce Guenter which I added in a comment on the original question, replacing the line "T=makemake.TARGETS" in makemake with "T=makemake.BRUCE" does the trick.

Re case insensitivity in OS X, I found this nugget on StackExchange:

> HFS+ (the Mac filesystem) is usually configured to be case insensitive but case preserving. This means that the file system will consider foo and FoO to be the same, but when you create a new file it will remember which letters where capitalized and which were not.

This strikes me as deeply weird behavior, but I haven't noticed any other related issues so I guess it doesn't break as much *nixy stuff as I would have expected it to. Something it *does* break is Bruce's original makemake script - fortunately the fix is trivial.